# get all from table django not only __str__(self)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

**models.py**

```
class club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    premiere_leauge = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**Views.py**

```
...
a = request.POST['club']
b = request.POST['city']

result = club.objects.all.get(name__exact=a, city__exact=b)
....
```

All is fine, however I believe result returns me:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Whatsover, I would like an equivalent of `'SELECT * FROM APP_CLUB where name='something and city='something';` so i would be able to do further manipulation in django like:

```
if result[3] is True:
       do_something()
```

Comment: Use `filter` instead of `get`.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to access boolean field named premiere leauge in table? How can I achieve that? by using filter, result[1] i get second object not column.

Comment: What about `result[1].premiere_leauge`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the offical [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/):

```
club.objects.filter(name='something')
```

It will return exactly the same as:

```
'SELECT * FROM APP_CLUB where name='something';
```

Example:

```
clubs = club.objects.filter(name__exact='something')

for club in clubs:
    if club.premier_league:
        do_something()
```

If you want to get only one club, then do it like this:

```
club = club.objects.get(name='something')
premier_league_value_of_club = club.premier_league
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to access boolean field named premiere leauge in table? How can I achieve that? by using filter, result[1] i get second object not column.

Comment: Added to answer

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` instead of `get`.

```
results = club.objects.filter(name__exact=a, city__exact=b)
```

You can then iterate over it to access all the model attributes like below

```
for result in results:
    print result.name, result.city, result.premier_league
```

Also, according to PEP-8, you should name your class name should ideally be titlecase `Club` instead of lowercase `club`.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to access boolean field named premiere leauge in table? How can I achieve that? by using filter, result[1] i get second object not column.

Comment: Added the appropriate code for accessing attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there, I think you're missing the [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#filter) function here. You can use it like this :

```
a = request.POST['club']
b = request.POST['city']

result = club.objects.filter(name__exact=a, city__exact=b)
```

It will return you a query set with the actual database entries.

The `__str__(self)` function is used in transforming your query set entry into a string, whether you string-cast it or print it.

Then about this :

```
if result[3] is True:
   do_something()
```

I don't get well what you mean about this, but if `3` is the id of the entry in the database, you then can do this :

```
if result.get(id=3).premiere_leauge:
    do_something()
```

But you might want to check if the entry with the id exists first to avoid errors :

```
if result.filter(id=3).exists() and result.get(id=3).premiere_leauge:
    do_something()
```

Comment: You should use `.get` for ids. It is much faster.

Comment: Use a try except block instead of hitting the database twice for the existence check.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify you query as shown below

```
result = club.objects.filter(name__exact=a, city__exact=b)
```

Good Luck !!

Comment: .all is not needed